# ASP.NET MVC Issue with docker container

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-mvc-4, docker-for-windows

I need to dockerize ASP.NET MVC 4 application. but when I hit localhost:8081 from my browser it keeps on loading with no response.

below dockerfile i am using for the same.

```
FROM microsoft/iis

SHELL ["powershell"] RUN "Install-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-45-ASPNET"

SHELL ["powershell"] RUN "Install-WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net45"

COPY . c:\\web-app

EXPOSE 8081

SHELL ["powershell"] RUN New-Website -Name ‘my-app’ -Port 8081 -PhysicalPath ‘c:\web-app’ -ApplicationPool ‘.NET v4.5′

ENTRYPOINT powershell

CMD Write-Host IIS Started… ; \  
    while ($true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 3600 }

docker build . -t ramiramilu/aspnetapp

docker run -d -p 8081:8081 ramiramilu/aspnetapp
```

Comment: your port in run command is 8081 not 8001, and that while loop looks infinite

Comment: yes , I am using 8081 only, while loop is infinite to run application continuously .

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to set the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` for running application continuously. See the following [microsoft/iis image page](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/iis/):

> There is no need to specify an ENTRYPOINT in your Dockerfile since the
>   microsoft/iis base image already includes an entrypoint application
>   that monitors the status of the IIS World Wide Web Publishing Service
>   (W3SVC).

Comment: I removed both the lines but still same issue .

Comment: Can you get the container's log? For example, by using `docker logs <container name>`